# Is emitting another Observable from finalize() operator a good practice?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, firebase-storage

Is it actually good to execute another observable with its own subscription inside `finalize()` operator?
I know, that putting this inside `subscribe()` is not a good practice, which leads to memory leak, etc. I'm currently working with Firebase Storage API and trying to upload an image to Database, and there is an issue, when you can't get correct status of uploading. So, I'm trying to understand, when I can get URL of image from database, when in response the amount of transferred bytes is equal to total bytes. But Firebase respond on this, that my image doesn't exist yet on server.

So I have to get an image URL in `finalize()` operator. Is it actually a good idea?

Also, could do it with using `debounceTime()`, but I want to keep code more clear and synchronous.

Also, searched for different solutions, and found some articles, where authors did the same thing

```
      this.storage.upload(filePath, this.selectedImage).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          rxFilter(res => res.bytesTransferred === res.totalBytes),
          switchMap(res => this.storage.ref(filePath).getDownloadURL())
        )
        .subscribe(url => {
          console.log(url);
        });
```

Comment: There are mechanisms in place to combine observables, such as `forkJoin`. You can also `.pipe` a callback to happen after the request complete.

Comment: @amphetamachine I need to get an URL exactly after I uploaded an image. Unfortunately, I can't get the correct status of uploading, I'm trying to know, that uploading is done, by comparing the amount of transferred bytes, but in this case, Firebase still responses with an error

Comment: Please post the code in question.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. It'll work, and I don't see another way to do it.

Comment: @amphetamachine, Yes, this code works. The question is aboutm if this practice is as bad as putting new Observable with subscribe inside first subscribe (memory leak, callback hell, etc), or not

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a bad practice and not recommended to do it. There is so many potential drawbacks and race conditions that are usually handled by RxJS that you would need to take care of on your own. Depending on your problem there are different ways to do that. I didn't understand the whole problem, but it sounds like you want to/should use `switchMap` or `concat`

Comment: That's the point, where problem of Firebase response is to come. When I'm trying to upload a file for 1.5 MB, on uploading Firebase object FireUploadTask has two Observable methods (`snapshotChanges()` and `percentageChanges()`), which allow to track the progress of uploading. However, after they emit last value with 100% upload, I try to immediately switch on next stream by `switchMap()`, and Firebase responds with an error, that my file does not yet exist in Database. So, I need to wait, maybe by using `debounceTime(0)` and after that response will be succesful

Comment: Also, I succeeded this by using just `last()` operator instead `filter()` in my code and this worked. Maybe, this works because of specific, how Firebase library is done for Angular (using ngZone).
Anyway, thanks for your answer, my main goal was to know, if executing another observable inside `finalize()` is as bad, as inside `subscribe()`